# Точка при окончании скобкой и кавычкой

Tags: пунктуация

Точка ставится после кавычек, и точка ставится внутри скобок, если в скобки взято цельное предложение. Но как быть, если цельное предложение в скобках само входит в прямую речь и заключается в кавычки?

Например:

*И сказал тот: «Думать надо. (Ведь не просто же всё так)»*

Где тут должна быть последняя точка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Делаем всё по правилам.

И сказал тот: «Думать надо. (Ведь не просто же всё так.)».

Точку внутри скобок и внутри кавычек (а она нужна, предложение закончено) отделяют от конечной точки повествовательного предложения целых два знака - закрывающая скобка и закрывающая же кавычка.